# Present Perfect questions?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

If we have sentences like (he is a teacher) can we make it in present perfect to be (he been a teacher)? If the answer no why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, “been” is a participle and not a stand-alone verb.

> He been a teacher

is not grammatical in standard English, and turning it into a question does not make it grammatical.

Secondly

> Has he been a teacher

is grammatical, but has a different meaning from

> Is he a teacher

The first asks whether he was a teacher in the **past**. The second asks whether he is a teacher **now**.